# How to access internal properties of F# HtmlProvider returned type?

Tags: f#, type-providers

I have the following F# HtmlProvider definition :

```
let temp = new HtmlProvider<"http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/data-structures/">()
```

In Visual Studio, temp offers following two properties

- Html
- ListsContainer

ListsContainer in turn provides access to individual list items like List1, List2, List3 etc as individual properties. However during runtime, if I view temp.ListsContainer in quick watch, I can see that there is an internal property called "**lists**"(of type **FSharpMap'string, HtmlList'**) which returns the same set of List items.

Is there a way to access the internal "lists" property?

Comment: What you want to get?